# Не передается кол-во товаров в корзину битрикс

Tags: битрикс

Доброго времени суток!
В компоненте catalog.section форма для изменения кол-ва товара, но значение стандартными средствами битрикс не передавалось. Полез разбираться, прогуглил, все что нашел попробовал, но не работает. В итоге пришел к скрипту который передает **/catalog/?action=ADD2BASKET&id=391&quantity=5** (*?action=ADD2BASKET&id=391 из переменной $arItemIDs['BUY_LINK'], переменная quantity задана и написана верно, вытаскивается jquery с инпута*), но почему то в итоге кол-во в корзине всегда равно 2, не могу понять почему так может быть?
Скрипт

```
$('.bx_bt_button.bx_medium').on('click',function(e){
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('success-btn')){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $(this).addClass('success-btn');
                        $(this).text('В корзине');
                        var quantity = "&quantity=" + $(this).parents(".catalog_item_buy").find('input[name="quantity"]').val();
                        var url = $(this).attr('href') + quantity;
                        console.log(url);
                        $.ajax({
                        type:'POST',
                        beforeSend:function(){
                            BX.showWait();
                        },
                        url:url,
                        success:function(data){
                            BX.onCustomEvent('OnBasketChange');
                            $('.bx_big.bx_bt_button.bx_cart').attr({'href':'/personal/cart/'});

                            BX.closeWait();
                        },
                    })
                }
        })
```

Стандартный JS не трогал

Comment: Вообще ни где нет значения 2, но всегда ставит кол-во товаров 2, хотя я и пишу больше
Кол-во идет в переменной quantity, здесь оно quantity=5

Comment: покажите код подключения компонента еще.

Comment: а почему вы думаете, что проблема в JS? В запросе цифра quantity правильная? Тогда дело явно не на клиенте.

Comment: В запросе цифра правильная в лог выводится. А где тогда искать?

Comment: на каком шаблоне компонента проверяете? если проверяете на стандартном неизмененном шаблоне `default`, то пишите в поддержку 1С-Битрикс. Иначе выкладывайте код подключения компонента и код шаблона, где осуществляете маипуляции с количеством.

Comment: На серверной стороне. Ведь если туда приходит правильная цифра, а выходит неправильное кол-во, то дело же явно не там, откуда отправилась цифра?